# I have two model with a has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models with the has_many association as shown below. My problem is that i cant get the id of either to save. I have a model_id in the site table and site_id in the model table to save the id. Am i missing or doing something wrong with these associations?

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :models
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :sites
end
```

Comment: That's not the correct way to do a many to many association. You need to either use has_many :through or has_and_belongs_to_many. See here for reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :model_sites, inverse_of: :site, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :models, through: :model_sites
end

class ModelSite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :site
  validates_presence_of :model, :site
end

class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_sites, inverse_of: :model, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sites, through: :model_sites
end
```

Comment: I would have to place a site_id and a model_id in the ModelSite table right?Will i have to create a new model_site if i want to store the id of each model?

Comment: correct.. you would need the additional model stated above with 2 foreign keys as you stated

Comment: What if im creating a new site and i want to choose all the models that belongs to that site. I can set <%= f.association :models %> and choose but it wont save. Unless i create a new model_site and choose from there then it actually gets saved. Is there a way to save is when creating a new site?